# Mixing Groovy MarkupBuilder with Converters

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-serialization

I am trying to inject XML fragments created by an XML converter into an MarkupBuilder.

However I cannot get the formatting correct, and it seems as though there is unnecessary intermediate serialisation steps.

```
import grails.converters.XML
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

//...

def writer = new StringWriter ()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder (writer)
xml.response {
   status ("OK")
   myList.each { it as XML } //Insert objects by converting to XML
}
println writer.toString()
```

The output required would be

```
<response>
  <status>OK</status>
  <foo>
     <field>5</field>
  </foo>
  <foo>
     <field>5</field>
  </foo>
</response>
```

My current attempt is this

```
def writer = new StringWriter ()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder (writer)
xml.response {
   status ("OK")
   myList.each {
     xml.mkp.yieldUnescaped ( it as XML )
   }
}
println writer.toString()
```

However currently each xml fragment is preceeded by

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Is there a groovier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The groovier way would be to pass your `writer` directly to the `render` method of the `XML` class as shown below.

```
def writer = new StringWriter ()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder (writer)
xml.response {
   status ("OK")
   def xmlist = myList as XML
   xmlist.render(writer)
}
```

You'll still have the encoding information one time though since `render` just writes it to any `writer` passed in.

I see 2 options to get rid of this encoding information:

- get the string representation of the XML as you did, and take off the encoding information as shown below (can be improved)
- write your own XML converter using Groovy [MarkupBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Creating+XML+using+Groovy%27s+MarkupBuilder) as explained in this [article](http://jan-so.blogspot.com/2008/08/grails-groovy-xml.html).

---

```
 xml.response {
    status ("OK")
    def xmlist = myList as XML
    xml.mkp.yieldUnescaped (xmlist.toString() - "&lt;?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?&gt;")
}
```